Getting error "Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' in your configuration."
I get the following error when running my application. It says to create a bean of type UserDetailsService, Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' in your configuration. Please let me know if I need to provide any more details.
Description:
Parameter 0 of constructor in dev.spring.hibernatedemo.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' in your configuration.
SecurityConfig.java:
package dev.spring.hibernatedemo.config;

import dev.spring.hibernatedemo.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import dev.spring.hibernatedemo.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers("/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

}

JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:
package dev.spring.hibernatedemo.security;

import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtHelper jwtHelper;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, JwtHelper jwtHelper) {
        this.jwtHelper = jwtHelper;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String requestHeader = request.getHeader("Authentication"); //Bearer
        log.info("Header: {}", requestHeader);
        String username = null;
        String token = null;

        if (requestHeader != null && requestHeader.startsWith("Bearer")) {
            token = requestHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtHelper.getUsernameFromToken(token);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.info("Illegal Argument while fetching the username !!");
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.info("Given jwt token is expired !!");
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            logger.info("Invalid header!!");
        }

        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            Boolean validatedToken = this.jwtHelper.validateToken(token, userDetails);
            if (validatedToken) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            } else {
                logger.info("Validation failed!!!");
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

Any help is appreciated!
Note: I followed Githublink instructions

check if this helps!!.

I get this error now
"Description:
The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:
┌─────┐
|  jwtAuthenticationFilter defined in file [C:\Users\erdalguzel\Desktop\Yeni klasör\hibernatedemo\hibernatedemo\target\classes\dev\spring\hibernatedemo\security\JwtAuthenticationFilter.class]
↑     ↓
|  securityConfig defined in file [C:\Users\erdalguzel\Desktop\Yeni klasör\hibernatedemo\hibernatedemo\target\classes\dev\spring\hibernatedemo\config\SecurityConfig.class]
└─────┘"

I would probably suggest to create GitHub issue with sample project repo you are referring so owner of the repo can clarify!!

I was able to solve it by adding beans to other file.
SecurityFilterConfig.java(Old SecurityConfig.java class)
package dev.spring.hibernatedemo.config;

import dev.spring.hibernatedemo.security.JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import dev.spring.hibernatedemo.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
public class SecurityFilterConfig {
    private JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth.requestMatchers("/api/security/authenticate").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
                .exceptionHandling(ex -> ex.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }
}

SpringSecurityConfig.java (new config class)
package dev.spring.hibernatedemo.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;

@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails adminUser = User.builder()
                .username("admin")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("admin"))
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .build();

        UserDetails normalUser = User.builder()
                .username("user")
                .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user"))
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(adminUser, normalUser);
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

